# Can we use one logic expression to compare multiple strings at once?

Tags: php, logical-operators

I'm trying to find a simpler way to check that one var does not equal multiple values in one comparison string.

I found that I can reduce code with something like `empty()` but not with `==` for string values.

`empty()` example to validate my concept.

```
if (empty($var_1 . $var_2 . $var_3) { echo 'All these vars are empty, run code...'; }
```

The above checks if $var_1, $var_2 and $var_3 are empty.

But is there a way to run something similar when using `!==` ?

See code explanation below...

```
Test('unknown_value');
echo PHP_EOL;
Test('value_1');

function Test($var = '') {

    // Below method is ideal...

    // if ($var !== 'value_1' . 'value_2' . 'value_3') {

    // Below method is 2nd to ideal

    // if ($var !== 'value_1' and 'value_2' and 'value_3') {

    // But I have to write it like below...
    // I'm looking for a way to not have to write $var !== for each comparison since they will all be not equal to

    if ($var !== 'value_1' and $var !== 'value_2' and $var !== 'value_3') {

        echo 'Failed!!!';

    }

    elseif ($var == 'value_1' or $var == 'value_2' or $var == 'value_3') {

        echo 'Accessed!!!';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **in_array**, like so:

```
if (in_array(trim($someVariable), [ 'this', 'that', 'the other'] )) {
    // $someVariable is one of the elements in the array
}
```

Comment: Great! This works. Thanks. I just had had to apply !in_array of course. Appreciate it! #Salute